# C++ determine if class is comparable

Tags: c++, templates, generics, comparable

I'm more or less Java programmer, so this might be a stupid question, but I didn't manage to find any simple solution.

I have a class like this in C++:

```
template<class T> class Node {...}
```

And I need T to be comparable - to have at least == < > operators defined. Is there any **simple** way to do this - or what is the best practice for this? In Java, it would be something like this:

```
public class Node<T extends Comparable> { ... }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `Node` is not a class, it's a class template.

Comment: Possibly related: [Detect operator support with decltype/SFINAE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5839357/636019)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

C++ templates are [duck-typed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4205130/1593077), so no interface or constraint is necessary, the compiler will use the comparison operators if they exist, and generate an error if not.

See also [this more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764816/103167).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to avoid cryptic errors (as you often get when the lack of comparability occurred deeply in the template instantiation tree), just use enable_if:

- If you have C++98 or C++03 compiler, boost::enable_if: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/utility/enable_if.html
- If you have C++11 compiler, std::enable_if: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if

In particular, take a look at "Enabling template class specializations" in the docs of boost::enable_if.

You often use enable_if with type_traits: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html

Of particular interest in your case might be the following ones:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference:/has_equal_to.html

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_not_equal_to.html

But see also has_greater, has_greater_equal, has_less, has_less_equal, etc.
// I'm actually somewhat surprised that there isn't a straightforward is_equality_comparable type-trait.

// EDIT: it appears I've found it, it's ::boost::is_equality_comparable::value in the Concept Traits Library:
http://neoscientists.org/~tschwinger/boostdev/concept_traits/libs/concept_traits/doc/

http://neoscientists.org/~tschwinger/boostdev/concept_traits/libs/concept_traits/doc/#StandardConceptTraits

However, it appears to be abandoned: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#Boost.ConceptTraits

An alternative solution is to use the Boost Concept Checking Library (BCCL), in particular applying the EqualityComparableConcept:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/concept_check/using_concept_check.htm

Yet another alternative: Boost.Generic -- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#Boost.Generic

Prensentation: http://github.com/boostcon/2011_presentations/raw/master/thu/Boost.Generic.pdf

Yet another alternative:
http://code.google.com/p/origin/source/browse/trunk/core/tests/concepts/equality_comparable.cpp

Comment: You might also take a look at the following:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.boost.devel/223294
http://www.martinecker.com/wiki/index.php?title=Detecting_the_Existence_of_Operators_at_Compile-Time

Answer (score 3):

This is now possible in C++20 Concepts library.

```
class Node<T> requires Compare<T> {...}
```

Though this will still throw an error if the concept is not satisfied, it makes it easier to understand what caused the error. You can write a wrapper around it to prevent errors.

Answer (score 2):

If your template class makes use of the operators you mentioned, the compiler will emit errors if the template type argument doesn't support such operators.