# Sorting of an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, structure, shallow-copy

I am programming in C. I have an array of structures. I need to print the array in sorted order based on an element of the structure. The main problem where I am stuck is I do not want to modify the original array.

For example:
My array is proctab[10].
This is the array of structure named pentry.

```
struct pentry
{
    int a;
    int b;
    char c;
}
```

I need to print as follows:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = a
a = 2, b = 1, c = d
a = 3, b = 0, c = e
a = 4, b = 1, c = a
a = 4, b = 2, c = a
```

and so on..
i.e. the result is sorted on a. but if a has same value for two structures in the array, the array should be sorted on b as well.

I want the original array proctab to remain intact.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: If it helps, I know in Java you'd just make the object implement `Comparable` and implement `compareTo` - I'm sure there's something similar in C?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838800/c-determine-if-class-is-comparable) seems to be related, perhaps it is useful?

Comment: Make a copy (`malloc`, `memcpy`) and then sort the copy (`qsort`)?

Comment: memcpy from string.h and qsort from stdlib.h will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To sort the items without messing with the original array, create a second array of references:

```
struct pentry plist[]= { { 1, 2, 'a' }, { 4, 8, 'z' }, { 2, 7, 'c' }, { 2, 1, 'e' }, { 5, 6, 'b' } ;
struct pentry (* pref)[5] ;

int compare( const struct pentry ** px, const struct pentry ** py )
{
  return ( (** px).a == (** py).a ) ? ( (** py).b - (** px).a ) : ( (** py).a - (** px).a ) ;
}

void dosort( struct pentry ** zdest, struct pentry * asrc, int n )
{
  int i ;
  struct pentry ** fill ;

  for ( i= n, fill= zdest ; ( i -- ) ; ) { *( fill ++)= asrc ++ ; }
  qsort( zdest, n, sizeof( * zdest ), compare ) ;
}

void show_sorted( struct pentry ** aref, int n )
{
  while ( n -- )
  {
    printf("%d %d %c\n", (** aref).a, (** aref).b, (** aref).c ) ;
    ++ aref ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  dosort( pref, plist, sizeof( plist) / sizeof( * plist)) ;
  show_sorted( pref, sizeof( plist) / sizeof( * plist)) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/).

*Edited to include changes to the OP's question.*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct tagPentry
{
    int a, b;
    char c;
} pentry;

/* Function used to compare the structs via qsort in 
the main() method */
int compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    pentry* p_a = (pentry*)a;
    pentry* p_b = (pentry*)b;

    /* Here, the compare function sorts based on the value of a 
    If p_a.a == p_b.a, then it will also sort by b*/
    if (p_a->a < p_b->a)
        return -1;
    if (p_a->a > p_b->a)
        return 1;
    else /* a is equal, so compare b */
    {
        if (p_a->b < p_b->b)
            return -1;
        if (p_a->b > p_b->b)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    /* Original array */
    pentry p[5];
    p[0].a = 1; p[0].b = 2; p[0].c = 'a';
    p[1].a = 4; p[1].b = 8; p[1].c = 'z';
    p[2].a = 2; p[2].b = 7; p[2].c = 'c';
    p[3].a = 2; p[3].b = 1; p[3].c = 'e';
    p[4].a = 5; p[4].b = 6; p[4].c = 'b';

    /* Temp array for output */
    pentry ptemp[5];
    memcpy(ptemp, p, sizeof p);

    /* Sort temp array */
    qsort(ptemp, 5, sizeof(pentry), compare);

    /* Print output */
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d %d %c\n", ptemp[i].a, ptemp[i].b, ptemp[i].c);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The compare function returns an integer depending on the comparison of the data within the structs. In this example, you can simply subtract the `pentry.a` values of each struct to determine which is lower. Since we want to compare `pentry.b` if, and only if, `pentry.a` for both structs are the same, we use a conditional `if` statement to compare the `pentry.b` values when necessary.

Comment: I modified the question a bit, can you please elaborate on that? Thanks

Comment: @ayushi Sure, changed.

Comment: Though it is not an issue with the specific sample data the OP provided, the comparator via-subtraction can cause underflow (or overflow) if the members of the structure are valued to do so. ex: `INT_MIN/2` and `INT_MAX/2+2`, or `INT_MIN` and any positive number, etc. For this reason it is advised *not* to use short-cut subtraction and rather use genuine logical comparison, enforcing a strict weak order, and return -1, 0 or 1. Better to start the habit early than discover it by-defect later down the road.

Comment: @WhozCraig Correct. Updated in the even the sample data is not a true example of the data set he/she is working with.

Comment: Why not use an array of pointers to the items in the original array. Saves quite some memory if the struct becomes bigger.

Comment: The question was tagged 'shallow-copy' but this solution is actually using a deep copy. Perhaps you could improve it by making the ptemp an array of pointers to the original structs and then sort that?

Comment: @Inisheer I am new to C. Can you explain int compare(const void *a, const void *b). Is this comparing the two structures a and b or do there a and b refer to the elements in the structure (int a and int b as i had specified in the question) ?

Comment: @ayushi It compares 2 of whatever are passed in to the parameters. In our case, it's two structs of type pentry. qsort doesn't know how to compare two objects. Therefore, you must supply it a compare method (you don't have to name it that) so the qsort function knows how to sort.

Answer (score 1):

With a hope you know sorting a simple integer array,

make a function that take two structures and decide on your own criteria which is greatest or in other words should come first than loop through the structure array with following code,

```
if( priorityof(arr[j],arr[j+1]) ==0)
SWAP
```

your function should return zero if they need to SWAP else return 1