# Most efficient way to process all items in an unknown container?

Tags: c++

I'm doing a computation in C++ and it has to be as fast as possible (it is executed 60 times per second with possibly large data). During the computation, a certain set of items have to be processed. However, in different cases, different implementations of the item storage are optimal, so i need to use an abstract class for that.

My question is, what is the most common and most efficient way to do an action with each of the items in C++? (I don't need to change the structure of the container during that.) I have thought of two possible solutions:

1. Make iterators for the storage classes. (They're also mine, so i can add it.) This is common in Java, but doesn't seem very 'C' to me:

   ```
   class Iterator {
   public:
       bool more() const;
       Item * next();
   }
   ```
2. Add sort of an abstract handler, which would be overriden in the computation part and would include the code to be called on each item:

   ```
   class Handler {
   public:
       virtual void process(Item &item) = 0;
   }
   ```

   (Only a function pointer wouldn't be enough because it has to also bring some other data.)
3. Something completely different?

The second option seems a bit better to me since the items could in fact be processed in a single loop without interruption, but it makes the code quite messy as i would have to make quite a lot of derived classes. What would you suggest?

Thanks.

**Edit**: To be more exact, the storage data type isn't exactly just an ADT, it has means of only finding only a specific subset of the elements in it based on some parameters, which i need to then process, so i can't prepare all of them in an array or something.

Comment: Iterators aren't very C, but they are *very* C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
```

Have a look at the existing containers provided by the C++ standard, and functions such as `for_each`.

For a comparison of C++ container iteration to interfaces in "modern" languages, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764816/103167).  The other answers have good examples of what the idiomatic C++ way looks like in practice.

Using templated functors, as the standard containers and algorithms do, will definitely give you a speed advantage over virtual dispatch (although sometimes the compiler can devirtualize calls, don't count on it).

Comment: Just to make sure, do i understand correctly that i should basically use the second approach, but use a template instead of the virtual method?

Comment: @Detheroc: If you implement an iterator using the same (duck-typed, not virtual via inheritance) interface as the standard containers, then you get all the existing standard algorithms, such as `for_each` and `transform` for free.  That's what I would do if you really are making a container.  From your question, you want a callback to be executed for a generated set of items, and in that case I'd go with #2 and accept a functor, via template if you care about performance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification, but there is a problem with the functor template. I cannot really pass it to the abstract container since virtual methods can't be templated. But i got some ideas on how to only call a virtual method once and not on all items, so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

C++ has iterators already. It's not a particularly "Java" thing. (Note that their interface is different, though, and they're much more efficient than their Java equivalents)

As for the second approach, calling a virtual function *for every element* is going to hurt performance if you're worried about throughput.

If you can (pre-)sort your data so that all objects of the same type are stored consecutively, then you can select the function to call *once*, and then apply it to all elements of that type. Otherwise, you'll have to go through the indirection/type check of a virtual function or another mechanism to perform the appropriate action for every individual element.

Answer (score 1):

What gave you the impression that iterators are not very C++-like? The standard library is full of them (see [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/iterator/)), and includes a wide range of algorithms that can be used to effectively perform tasks on a wide range of standard container types.

If you use the STL containers you can save re-inventing the wheel and get easy access to a wide variety of pre-defined algorithms. This is almost always better than writing your own equivalent container with an ad-hoc iteration solution.

Comment: His particular iterator API is not idiomatic C++.  `more` should be called `operator!=(end)` and `next` should be split into `operator*()` and `operator++()`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: not disagreeing. Iterators in C++ are definitely quite different to other languages (the OP's example is more Java-like), but do exist. The OP seemed (to me) to think that iterators (in general) are not very C++-like, but I concede he may have meant that the particular style he described is not c++-like. Regardless, the point is that the STL *does* include iterators for standard containers, and IMHO using such is always preferable to a home-brew solution (where feasible, of course).

Answer (score 0):

A function template perhaps:

```
template <typename C>
void process(C & c)
{
    typedef typename C::value_type type;
    for (type & x : c) { do_something_with(x); }
}
```

The iteration will use the containers iterators, which is generally as efficient as you can get.

You can specialize the template for specific containers.